# how put data to newly created folder with current date in python

Tags: python, api, arcgis

I found this code

```
#! usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime
import os

today = datetime.now()

if today.hour < 12:
    h = "00"
else:
    h = "12"

os.mkdir("/home/xxx/" + today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+ h)
```

which helps me to create a new folder with the current date, but I need to move zip (AGOL-GDB) to this new folder. I don't want to change directory every time i am running my script.

```
outputFolder= r"C:\WORKING\OUT"
```

I am using Jupyter notebook, Python 3 with arcgis API.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just update your output path to to the new folder instead of copying from your cwd to the new dir? To answer your original question though:

```
import shutil 
file = r'some\file.zip'
output_path = r'C:\data'
shutil.copy(file, output_path)
```

This will copy `file` to `output_path`. Then you can delete it from cwd or whatever you want.